# Java JDT parser. Get variable type of VariableDeclarationFragment

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

I've been implementing a Java parser with JDT and I can't figure out how to get a variable type when its node's type is *VariableDeclarationFragment*.

I found out how to get a variable type only when it comes to *VariableDeclaration*

My code is the following.

```
public boolean visit(VariableDeclarationFragment node) {
    SimpleName name = node.getName();

    System.out.println("Declaration of '" + name + "' of type '??');

    return false; // do not continue 
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out how to get the type from VariableDeclarationFragment. I just have to get its parent, which is a FieldDeclaration, then I can access its variable type.

Comment: Actually, it can also be a VariableDeclarationStatement or a VariableDeclarationExpression.

Answer (score 1):

This may be not the best type-safety solution, but it worked for my case.
I'm simply extracting type which is being handled in node by calling toString() method.

```
    public boolean visit(VariableDeclarationFragment node) {
            SimpleName name = node.getName();
            String typeSimpleName = null;

            if(node.getParent() instanceof FieldDeclaration){
                FieldDeclaration declaration = ((FieldDeclaration) node.getParent());
                if(declaration.getType().isSimpleType()){
                    typeSimpleName = declaration.getType().toString();
                }
            }

            if(EXIT_NODES.contains(typeSimpleName)){
                System.out.println("Found expected type declaration under name "+ name);
            }

            return false;
    }
```

With help of checking type of node, and previous declaration of EXIT_NODE list of classes simple names, it gives me pretty much confidence that I'm at the right spot.

HTH a little.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [JDT API docs](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FVariableDeclarationFragment.html), `VariableDeclarationFragment` extends `VariableDeclaration`, so you can use the same methods to get the type for either one.

Comment: Actually when it comes to VariableDeclaration, I get the variable type with getStructuralProperty(SingleVariableDeclaration.TYPE_PROPERTY). However, I already tried calling this same method in VariableDeclarationFragment and then it throws an exception, saying that the Node does not have this property

Comment: @MarceloNoguti My guess is that the `VariableDeclarationFragment` doesn't necessarily contain the type information, then. It is a *fragment* after all.

Comment: I did research a lot about this. I'm afraid you're right and it's a shame. I think I'll have to work around to solve this problem after all