# Datatype of a variable using ASTParser in java

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing

```
VariableDeclarationFragment node;

SimpleName name = node.getName();
```

If `node.getName()` is of type `String`, then output should be `String`.
If `node.getName()` is of type `Integer`, then output should be `Integer`.

Is there a way to do this using `ASTParser` or otherwise?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java JDT parser. Get variable type of VariableDeclarationFragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18454697/java-jdt-parser-get-variable-type-of-variabledeclarationfragment)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [resolveBinding()](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/VariableDeclaration.html#resolveBinding%28%29) operation on the VariableDeclarationFragment. It associates the variable with its type. The binding may not be available depending on the status of the AST construction.